# How do I checkout all submodules and sub-submodules?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

We have a git repository, with submodules. Inside one of the submodules is another submodule.

When we download the repository with git --recurse-submodules, it doesnt checkout the sub-submodules.

How do you achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command and it will recursively clone all submodules and nested submodules.
`git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: FYI, according to the [docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt), this *should* be equivalent to using `--recurse-submodules`.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl: it should be, but there have been some bugs in some versions of Git, so if it isn't, you probably have one of those bugs. :-)

Comment: Hm, okay thanks everyone. Seems a bit of a daft bug! Maybe we should update our git. Thanks